# forward starting interest rate swap trade settlement date

Tags: swaps, interest-rate-swap, forward-start

Say today is 13rd Dec 2022,
For a spot staring swap, its settlement date would be 15th Dec 2022 assuming the settlment offset is 2 days.

What is the settlement date for a one year forward starting swap trade ?
is the settlement date  13rd Dec 2023 or 15th Dec 2023 ?

Comment: 15th  - it's based on the effective date (settlement date).